# React onClick setState then run function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Good day!

Is it possible to trigger multiple functions on the onClick event ?

I would like when the user clicks on my button to setState and then run a function.
I managed to update my state but I am not sure how to proceed to add the second step which would be to run my function called "goToOrderTemplate()"

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-primary"
  style={{ width: 250 }}
  onClick={() =>
    this.setState({
      auth: this.passwordValidation()
    })
  }
>
```

Any help woul dbe greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just do it after the setState ?, if you need to wait for the setState to perform, there is a second parameter callback function to setState. But you should use it in last case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` takes a second parameter, which is a callback that gets called back when the state was set. You should use that if `goToOrderTemplate` depends on the state being set:

```
this.setState({
  auth: this.passwordValidation(),
}, goToOrderTemplate)
```

In the general case that you want to call two functions, just do that:

```
onClick={() => { 
  this.setState({
    auth: this.passwordValidation(),
  });
  goToOrderTemplate();
}}
```

Comment: Using callback to `setState` should not be the prefered solution. We do not even know what he is trying to do. Using cb to `setState` should be done only in rare case scenario. I doubt this is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function to the this.setState as second argument

```
this.setState({
  auth: this.passwordValidation()
}, () => {
  goToOrderTemplate()
})
```

Comment: 1. The answer was given at the same moment of the answer above
2. The answer marked as right not ensure that the function will be executed after the setState.
3. Yes, the arrow function is useless =]